# Way to approach a self-updating audio site based off a directory

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm new to the site and also to web developing, and I'd like to thank everyone on the site; through your answers I've been able to get to where I am now with my first website. I hope this question isn't too vague, but it is more conceptual, as I would like some guidance on how to approach programming javascript for this site's needs.

I've completed most of the html and css styling with only the javascript remaining

My site will consist of 7 audio players running off of the MediaElement.js script. Instead of being static and having to manually change the src files to change the audio, I would like the site to auto update everyday. The audio files will be kept in a folder and I will probably add more and more files as time goes by. I will try to program something so that with each day, the songs on the website move down that list (i.e. the song in the first player today will be in the last player a week from today, and no longer on the site 8 days from today)

at the same time, I have an  in each player for the cover art and will have to retrieve the embedded art from the id3 tags, which I've researched already. So I guess my question is, how should I put this big equation together, in terms of efficiency and the script not freezing?

I was thinking about calling the "function updateSource (){" for the each audio player, but what would be the best way to have each player follow the list of songs in a linear progression?

Thanks for your input, I know I still have a lot to learn!